# Syntax Explanation for End Keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

Here is a file for an app I'm trying to make (from the Hartl tutorial, it is just a basic twitter app). The site wasn't loading until I added the third 'end' at the very bottom which was suggested by the browser, but I can't figure out why this is needed. I get all the "def"'s need to have a keyword "end" but why are there 3 "end"'s at the end of the code.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

    def index
     @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end 


    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def destroy
      User.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "User deleted."
      redirect_to users_url
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def edit
    end

      def update
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end


      def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end

     def following
      @title = "Following"
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'show_follow'
     end

      def followers
        @title = "Followers"
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
        render 'show_follow'
      end



   private

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                     :password_confirmation)
      end

      # Before filters


      def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
      end

      def admin_user
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
      end
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `end` to `update` and `create` methods as the methods are not closed. 
Also, out of the 3 `end` at the bottom, remove the **two** `end` leaving just `one` end for your class.

```
    def update
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end    ## This end was missing

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end   ## This end was missing
```

Comment: I just answered a very similar question. The common pattern is poorly indented code. +1

Answer (score 0):

`following` and the private methods were defined inside the `create` method, which was created inside the `update` method. I doubt you wanted to do that. So the three `end`s at the end of the file close `create`, then `update`, and then the class. You need an `end` after `if` clauses, maybe that's what caused the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're missing the end on the **update** method (probably an oversight caused by bad indentation).
2. You're missing the end on the **create** method (probably an oversight caused by bad indentation).
3. The class itself needs an end

Correctly formatted it should look like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
   @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end 


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```